# Match listing with given words separated by given list of separators with single regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to detect listing of weekdays names in sentences, separated by commas, word AND and "&" symbol with regex.

Can i mix this patterns:

`\b(sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)(?:s)?\b`

`(,|\band\b|&)\s?`

So i can get this result:

"This is just **monday,** nobody cares about mondays." `false` no listings

"I like **sundays and saturdays**" `true` got more than 1 matches, AND separator

"Happy fun time at **tuesday, wednesday, friday**, 11pm-12am" `true` 3 weekdays, comma separator

Answer (score 2):

Well this is an exhaustive solution with some `alterations`.

**Regex:**

`((sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)s?,?\s+){2,}|((sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)s?,?\s+)+(and\s|&\s)((sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)s?,?)`

**Explanation:**

- `((sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)s?,?\s+){2,}` matches the list of days separated by comma.

---

If there is **and** or **&** before last day of week then this part will do the matching.

- `((sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)s?,?\s+)+` matches the **list** of words before **`and`** or **`&`**.
- `(and\s|&\s)((sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)s?,?)` matches the last day of week.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aD7sM0/4)**</kbd>

Comment: You give me a good clue. Thank you. But i get more clear solution

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**

```
(((sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday)(?:s)?\s?(?:,|and|&)?\s?){2,})
```

[Try demo](https://regex101.com/r/aD7sM0/6)